# CNTK Faster RCNN image prediction result boundary box size always follows the image size

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-recognition, cntk

I am new to CNTK and all Machine Learning frameworks. I tried to do image recognition process with Faster RCNN with CNTK. I modified the "DetectionDemo.py" to refer to my own dataset (positive, negative, testImages, and finally a prediction image).

The dataset are basemap areas (you can imagine something like google map). Some areas are considered category A (labeled as A), some areas are considered category B (labeled as B), some areas are category C (labeled as C), etc. So I would like to predict the areas and its category by using other set of basemap into the CNTK as the prediction image.

No matter how big is my prediction image size, I always use the same zoom level, the same resolution (dpi, meters per cell).

On my first prediction image (around 3200 x 3200 pixels), the system produced few prediction boundary boxes like in average around half size of my prediction image size. So I expected to have the same size of prediction boundary box size when I used a larger image size. However, when I used a larger image size (around 9000 x 9000 pixels) for prediction, the system produced few prediction boundary boxes also in average around half size of my prediction image size. And this kept going. When I put a prediction image that was multiple times larger in size (around 18000 x 18000 pixels) and ran the prediction again, the system produced few prediction boundary boxes also in average around half size of my prediction image size. During all of these, the training data were the same, did not change. It still used the same model and settings.

Is this normal in CNTK? How to have a stable size of prediction boundary box result? Why the size of prediction boundary boxes result do not try to follow the average size of the labeled training data boundary?

Looking forward to some suggestions...